# Problem when linking c++ program with lpsolve api

Tags: c++, linker, g++, linear-programming, lpsolve

I'm facing some issues when linking my c++ program, here is what I do : 
`g++ tp.cpp -llpsolve55 -lcolamd -ldl -o MyExe`
and the command-line return me this :

`/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llpsolve`
`collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status`

But I've already installed lpsolve, it appear in Synapatic as installed and I even installed it via the terminal

Comment: may be you should put lpsolve on the Path

Comment: How can I do that ?

Comment: it depends of your operative system

Comment: my OS is Ubuntu Mate

Comment: I solved this problem, now I'm trying to run MyExe (file) and I get this :  ./MyExe: error while loading shared libraries: liblpsolve55.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: Put the directory with the library into the LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable.

Comment: You've not included the relevant portions of the error code, which explain why `ld` failed. It's in the line or two before the one you posted. It's most likely an unresolved external issue, but it's impossible to help without knowing the rest of the error message.

Comment: To solve my previous problem I put this absolute path of lpsolve api : g++ tp.cpp /usr/lib/lp_solve/liblpsolve55.so -lcolamd -ldl -o MyExe

Comment: I put all my message error --> ./MyExe: error while loading shared libraries: liblpsolve55.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
I don't understand

Comment: Are you using `dlopen()` in your program too? I'm wondering just because I noticed you link with the `dl` library. You don't need that if you link with the library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `/usr/lib/lp_solve` is not in the normal search path for libraries, you can add that path to your executeable when linking. Also note that libraries should typically come last:

```
g++ -o MyExe tp.cpp -L /usr/lib/lp_solve  -Wl,-rpath,/usr/lib/lp_solve -llpsolve55 -lcolamd
```

The `-L` argument adds the directory to the list of directories to look for libraries in when doing the linking.

`-Wl` tells the compiler to pass on what follows to the linker.

The linkers `-rpath,<path>` argument tells it to add `<path>` to `MyExe` so it can find the library when you later run the program.

Comment: Even by running this command I still get the same error that I had : ./MyExe: error while loading shared libraries: liblpsolve55.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: Perfect ! it worked, thanks, what was the problem ...?

Comment: You are welcome! I added an extra `/lib` after `ip_solve` in my previous version. Bad eyesight. :-) Note that you don't need `-ldl` unless you use the `dlopen()` family of functions.

Comment: Oh okay haha don't worry. And what is the purpose of the -L argument, and -W1 ?

Comment: @ADL92 Added explanation (and I removed `-ldl` from the command line since I assume  that you don't use `dlopen()`).